# AWS Redshift Node Failure - is the entire cluster unavailable despite having mutliple nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I was looking at the official [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/) for Redshift. They indicated that if a "Node goes down, the cluster remains unavailable while Redshift replaces the node. I was wondering if  this applies to Redshift clusters having multiple nodes? Redshift does support upto 120 Nodes - so if 1 node goes down - is the entire Redshift cluster still unavailable?

(My confusion is that I wasnt able to properly discern whether FAQ was talking about a cluster with 1 node or multiple)

Answer (score 3):

For a single node cluster the single compute node is also the leader node.  Copies of node data is not replicated on other nodes since there are no other nodes to copy it to.  A disk failure or a node failure will cause the database to crash completely and will need to restarted and restored from an S3 snapshot.  Because of this single node Redshift "clusters" are not recommended for production workloads.  These are meant for trying out Redshift and dev work.

In a multi-node Redshift cluster the data from every compute node is replicated in some set of the other nodes.  If a disk fails on a node then the data can be fetched from these other nodes/disks until the disk is replaced and the data is brought back in to the new disk.  This is all seamless and unless you look at the logs you likely won't notice.

A compute node failure will cause a short pause in the operation of you cluster while a replacement node is provisioned.  Once the replacement is up the cluster will start executing queries using the backup node data from the other nodes.  In a short while the node will be "refilled" with all of its data.  Node failures are much rarer than disk failures.

If the leader node fails, on any size cluster, the database will crash and will need to be restored from S3 snapshot.  Leader node failures is very rare but therefore Redshift is not a full HA database.  Sometimes people will use 2 Redshift clusters and set up a main and backup cluster for this reason.

Comment: If the leader node fails, the database will crash and will need to be restored from S3 snapshot. What if data is  coming from some different Datasource like DynamoDB or any other ?